# Nuxt js Custom cursor event listener not working after route change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, addeventlistener, gsap

I'm currently building a new website for our studio but can't get the custom cursor to work properly. Here's a custom cursor built with gsap and the result was great except when I navigate to another route and back to the home page, the mouseover event stops working and I can't find a reason why.

What could be causing this and how could this be fixed?

Thank you in advance!

Here's the CustomCursor component:

```
    <template>
      <div class="custom-cursor">
        <div id="cursor-big" class="custom-cursor__ball custom-cursor__ball--big"></div>
        <div id="cursor-small" class="custom-cursor__ball custom-cursor__ball--small"></div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      import gsap from "gsap";
    
      export default {
        props: {
          hoverClass: {
            type: String,
            default: 'cursorHover'
          }
        },
        mounted () {
          const cursorBig = document.getElementById('cursor-big'),
                cursorSmall = document.getElementById('cursor-small'),
                links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
                withClassHover = document.getElementsByClassName(this.hoverClass),
                withHover = [...links, ...withClassHover];
    
          // Event Listeners
          document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
          document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseHover);
          document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseHoverOut);
          document.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
            cursorBig.style.opacity = 1;
            cursorSmall.style.opacity = 1;
          });
          document.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            cursorBig.style.opacity = 0;
            cursorSmall.style.opacity = 0;
          });
          withHover.forEach((element) => {
            element.addEventListener("mouseover", onMouseHover);
            element.addEventListener("mouseout", onMouseHoverOut);
          })
    
          // Event Handlers
          function onMouseMove(e) {
            cursorSmall.style.opacity = 1;
            gsap.to(cursorBig, 0.4, {
              x: e.clientX - 18.5,
              y: e.clientY - 18.5
            });
            gsap.to(cursorSmall, 0.1, {
              x: e.clientX - 4,
              y: e.clientY - 4
            });
          }
          function onMouseHover() {
            gsap.to(cursorBig, 0.3, {
              scale: 3,
            });
          }
          function onMouseHoverOut() {
            gsap.to(cursorBig, 0.3, {
              scale: 1,
            });
          }
        }
      };
    </script>
    
    <style>
      @media screen and (min-width:1100px) {
        * {
          cursor: none !important;
        }
    
        .custom-cursor__ball {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          mix-blend-mode: difference;
          z-index: 99999;
          opacity: 0;
          pointer-events: none;
          transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
        }
    
        .custom-cursor__ball--big {
          content: "";
          width: 35px;
          height: 35px;
          background: white;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
    
        .custom-cursor__ball--small {
          content: "";
          width: 6px;
          height: 6px;
          background: #fff;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: mounted will only fire once, when you route off somewhere else the dom elements are lost then once you come back the events are no longer attached to the elements because they were destroyed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation! Which hook should I use then?

Comment: There is no hook you can use, your need to either invoke this component outside `<Nuxt/>` within your template so it's not destroyed or make sure it is fully destroyed by adding a v-if on it or a randomizer prop `:instance="Math.random()"` when you create it which has a watcher on `instance` to reinvoke the handlers which then you add in all the beforeDestroy hooks to remove the custom event handlers, add onMouseMove, onMouseHover, onMouseHoverOut as methods add for mouseenter, mouseleave methods like the others, set cursorBig and cursorSmall into data, then make an init method which you call

Comment: If I'll go with the v-if solution, how do I tell the v-if when to show it and when to hide it?

Comment: v-if will trigger the beforeDestroy which as said you need to add all the document.removeEventListener's, and when its truthy again mounted will be called, if you make a codesandbox ill rewrite it so it works

Comment: I have now created a codesandbox with the same code as in my real project. Here's the link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-cookies-yvr2z?file=/components/customCursor.vue

Comment: @LawrenceCherone btw you have to go to the full screen mode to see how it works.

Comment: [working snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-rain-i7v0q?file=/components/CustomCursor.vue), for some reason $nextTick stack seems to not happen after render, so wrapping in a setTimeout with 100ms delay or so fixes it, reason it borks is the button is not on the dom when your getElementsByClassName call fires

Comment: I wrapped it in a setTimeout with 100ms delay but still does not work:/

Comment: see my example, its working for me, are you opening in a new window?

Comment: Oh yeah my bad I didn't see it there. Now it's working perfectyl! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Moved from comments:

- Issue: Elements with `cursorHover` class are not on the DOM after they have been removed when you route off somewhere else. Mounted only fires once.

Fix: Handle reinitiating your events onto the dom elements, and destroy your custom event handlers as the route changes.

```
<template>
  <div class="custom-cursor">
    <div
      id="cursor-big"
      class="custom-cursor__ball custom-cursor__ball--big"
    ></div>
    <div
      id="cursor-small"
      class="custom-cursor__ball custom-cursor__ball--small"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gsap from "gsap";

export default {
  name: "CustomCursor",
  props: {
    hoverClass: {
      type: String,
      default: "cursorHover",
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cursorBig: null,
      cursorSmall: null,
      withHover: [],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    "$route.path"() {
      console.log("route change");
      this.destroy();
      this.$nextTick(this.init);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted");
    this.$nextTick(this.init);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log("beforeDestroy");
    this.destroy();
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      console.log("init");
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.cursorBig = document.getElementById("cursor-big");
        this.cursorSmall = document.getElementById("cursor-small");

        this.withHover = [
          ...document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
          ...document.getElementsByClassName(this.hoverClass),
        ];

        this.withHover.forEach((element) => {
          element.addEventListener("mouseover", this.onMouseHover);
          element.addEventListener("mouseout", this.onMouseHoverOut);
        });
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseHover);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseHoverOut);
        document.addEventListener("mouseenter", this.onMouseEnter);
        document.addEventListener("mouseleave", this.onMouseLeave);
      }, 100);
    },
    destroy() {
      console.log("destroy");
      this.withHover.forEach((element) => {
        element.removeEventListener("mouseover", this.onMouseHover);
        element.removeEventListener("mouseout", this.onMouseHoverOut);
      });
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseHover);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseHoverOut);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseenter", this.onMouseEnter);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseleave", this.onMouseLeave);
    },
    onMouseEnter() {
      this.cursorBig.style.opacity = 1;
      this.cursorSmall.style.opacity = 1;
    },
    onMouseLeave() {
      this.cursorBig.style.opacity = 0;
      this.cursorSmall.style.opacity = 0;
    },
    onMouseMove(e) {
      this.cursorSmall.style.opacity = 1;
      gsap.to(this.cursorBig, 0.4, {
        x: e.clientX - 18.5,
        y: e.clientY - 18.5,
      });
      gsap.to(this.cursorSmall, 0.1, {
        x: e.clientX - 4,
        y: e.clientY - 4,
      });
    },
    onMouseHover() {
      gsap.to(this.cursorBig, 0.3, {
        scale: 3,
      });
    },
    onMouseHoverOut() {
      gsap.to(this.cursorBig, 0.3, {
        scale: 1,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  * {
    cursor: none !important;
  }

  .custom-cursor__ball {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  }

  .custom-cursor__ball--big {
    content: "";
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .custom-cursor__ball--small {
    content: "";
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

i currently facing the same issue, but it solved after adding,

> this.$next.tick()

so, i just attached the handler when the components is mounted :

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.transitionController()
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        this.transitionController()
      })
    })
},
```